# No data returned when SSL enabled for REST server via services module

Tags: services, ssl

I am running a LAMP stack on CentOS with Drupal 6 and the latest Services module. Over HTTP the REST server I have running works fine and behaves as expected.

When I installed an SSL certificate I forced all port 80 traffic to 443 (SSL). This worked fine for Drupal but has caused the REST server to return no data. Naturally I have removed the force SSL and allowed both HTTP and HTTPS for the time being.

I am testing via Fiddler, which when used to access the endpoint over HTTP, returns the expected data. Testing over HTTPS I receive no data. Do I need to make a configuration change to the REST server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so I had some help in where to look on StackOverflow but ultimately I discovered my problem myself.

The issue was that I was using a name based Virtual Host rather than an IP one.

So to be clear, I had:

```
<VirtualHost MyDomain:443>
```

and I needed

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
```